# firstResponder in NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've got two classes. ManagingViewController, a subclass of NSViewController, and ViewController, a subclass auf ManagingViewController. In Viewcontroller I've got a NSTextField which I want to become the firstResponder, but I didn't manage that.

So it is nearly the same like the Chapter 29 in Hillegass' book Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X  ([Download of the book's examples](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/cocoa%C2%AE_programming_for_mac%C2%AE_os_x_3rd_edition)) except of an NSTextField which is set to firstResponder.

Can anybody point me to the correct way?

Comment: Can you post the code you're working with?

Comment: Look at the examples of the book (29_ViewSwapping). Only added `IBOutlet NSTextField *test;` and `IBOutlet NSTextField *test2;` to DepartmentViewController.h and two NSTextFields to the DepartmentView.nib

Comment: like i said... using the interface builder. you can set which ever easily

Comment: It's the same. There is no `initialFirstResponder` for views. Only windows have.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set the text field as the first responder by using `-[NSWindow makeFirstResponder:]`.

Since this is an `NSWindow` method, it only makes sense after you’ve added the corresponding view to the window, i.e., after you’ve added the view as a subview inside the window view hierarchy. In the book’s example, this happens when you set the view as the content view of the box inside the window. For example:

```
- (void)displayViewController:(ManagingViewController *vc) {
    // Try to end editing
    NSWindow *w = [box window];
    …

    // Put the view in the box
    NSView *v = [vc view];
    [box setContentView:v];

    // Set the first responder
    if ([vc class] == [ViewController class]) {
        [w makeFirstResponder:[(ViewController *)vc myTextField]];
    }
}
```

This assumes `ViewController` exposes a getter method called `-myTextField`.

You can make this more generic by having your view controllers expose a method that returns the object that the view controller recommends as the first responder. Something like:

```
@interface ManagingViewController : NSViewController
…
- (NSResponder *)recommendedFirstResponder;
@end

@implementation ManagingViewController
…
- (NSResponder *)recommendedFirstResponder { return nil; }
@end
```

And, in your concrete subclasses of `ManagingViewController`, have `-recommendedFirstResponder` return the object that should be the window’s first responder:

```
@implementation ViewController
…
- (NSResponder *)recommendedFirstResponder { return myTextField; }
@end
```

Having done that, you can change your `-displayViewController:` to something like:

```
- (void)displayViewController:(ManagingViewController *vc) {
    // Try to end editing
    NSWindow *w = [box window];
    …

    // Put the view in the box
    NSView *v = [vc view];
    [box setContentView:v];

    // Set the first responder
    NSResponder *recommendedResponder = [vc recommendedFirstResponder];
    if (recommendedResponder) [w makeFirstResponder:recommendedResponder];
}
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for. Implemented it in my NSViewController, and it works.

I did it as @optional, however, as not all of my views care about having a field become a first responder.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `[[myTextField window] makeFirstResponder:myTextField];` ?

Comment: Just tried this in `-awakeFromNib` but it doesn't work for me. The firstResponder is still the wrong field.

Comment: A Custom View has no initialFirstResponder. Only a window has, so I think I have to call the window from inside the NSViewController (like your first suggestion). But I have no idea how.

Comment: @lueda: `-awakeFromNib` in which class?

Answer (score -3):

simple. Goto you xib file in interface builder. right click the first responder field. it will show the connection , remove the connection and connect it to the desired responder. let me know if this works

Comment: Look at the comments on the answer above!