# Saving and restoring NSWindow state: can't restore firstRepsonder

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nscoder

I'm working on using `encodeRestorableState`/`restoreStateWithCoder` to save and restore the state of a window. (I'm doing this manually because I want to explicitly save my window state in the document and not just rely on the OS restoring its state as part of restoring the application state)

The problem I'm having is that when it restores, an error is logged in the console that it can't restore the first responder because the view in question has its window set to nil.

I tried calling `makeFirstResponder(nil)` before encoding, but then the window is its own first responder and an exception is thrown because it can't encode itself.

I'm doing this from my window controller's `windowDidLoad`. Doing it in `awakeFromNib` didn't make a difference.

So is there a way I can either prevent the window from saving/restoring the first responder, or ensure that the first responder view is installed in the window first?

Comment: From where and how do you call `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:` and `restoreStateWithCoder:`?

Comment: I call `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder` in the window controller's `windowWillClose:`, saving the result to a file manually. Then in `windowDidLoad` I read the file back in and call `restoreStateWithCoder`. I have also tried restoring in `awakeFromNib` instead, with the same result. Aside from the first responder issue it's working fine.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266634/firstresponder-in-nsviewcontroller. Let me know for questions.

Comment: @LukeAhn That doesn't relate to encoding/decoding windows.